# Upload photo to fanpage from application user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading, fan-page, facebook-as3-api

I have a Facebook application in which a user can upload photos to a facebook fanpage. I am having trouble figuring out how to upload the photo as the user that is using the application. Currently I can have the fanpage upload the photo as itself, so the fanpage loses the author of the photo.

To do this I am grabbing the fan page's auth token(which I am assuming is the reason the app is posting as the fan page) and using that to pass to the "photos" method of the api. I am using the AS3 api, but I am sure the concept is the same no matter which api I am using.

```
var values:Object = {message:"message here", name:"title here"};
values.access_token = fanPageAccessToken;
values.image = file;
Facebook.api('fanPageId/photos/', handleUploadComplete, values,'POST');
```

When I change to the user's access token the image is uploaded to the user's photos. Even though I am specifying the fanPageId, it gets uploaded to the user's photos.

I am struggling here. Does anyone have an idea I can try, or some insight to share?

Thank you so much, I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every possible API combination to post a photo to a page from the user, but it's no use. A user cannot post a photo to a page. Even creating an album on the page and then posting to that doesn't work.